¿Cómo agregar un botón de regreso o para "volver atrás" en html?
Estoy realizando un juego llamado wordle, quiero agregar un botón de regreso que diga volver a jugar o volver atrás pero no se como hacerlo. Este es mi código html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
         <title>wordle PPY</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
         <script src="script.js" defer></script>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" charset="UTF-8" />
         <!-- <script src="tarea.js" defer><script> -->
     </head>
     <body>
         <h1>Wordle PPY</h1>
         <input type="text" id="guess-input" />
         <button id="guess-button">intentar</button>
         <div id="grid"></div>
         <p id="guesses"></p>
     </body>
</html> 


El HTML por sí solo no puede hacer gran cosa, necesitarás JS si lo quieres hacer en front o PHP si lo quieres hacer en backend. Para lo que necesitas un simple enlace <a href="index.php">Volver</a> debería ser suficiente.

Pero tienes una pagina "atrás" para volver o sería en la misma pagina todo?? Como ya te dijo David, si es volver al inicio ahí tienes el botón

Para realizar la acción pretendida con solo etiquetas de html sin añadir javascript en tu código ni llamadas a librerías externas puedes utilizar le método "history.back();", ya reconocido por el navegador y con el cual siempre que se haga clic en el elemento que lo contiene volverá a ruta anterior a la que se accedió en el navegador. En este ejemplo verás como he modificado tu código tan solo añadiendo el elemento "button" con la acción mencionada mediante la propiedad "onclick".


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
         <title>wordle PPY</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
         <script src="script.js" defer></script>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" charset="UTF-8" />
         <!-- <script src="tarea.js" defer><script> -->
     </head>
     <body>
         <h1>Wordle PPY</h1>
         <input type="text" id="guess-input" />
         <button id="guess-button">intentar</button>
         <div id="grid"></div>
         <p id="guesses"></p>
         <!-- código añadifo -->
         <button onclick="history.back();">VOLVER</button> 
     </body>
</html> 



Aquí comparto un enlace a la documentación sobre el uso y comportamiento de este método History.
